# I made the 2048 game but its not running as it was supposed to

Tags: c++

I decided to make the 2048 game. It is a very popular game for beginners.

The game is almost complete now but there's this error because of which my game keeps getting closed again and again as soon as I make my first move. I have tested a lot thoroughly and couldn't trace the error(s). I am new to programming.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
#include<ctime>
#include<string>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<fstream>
#include<Windows.h>
using namespace std;

HANDLE hConsole = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);

const int limit = 4;
int board[limit][limit] = {};
int score = 0;
string name;
int highestScore;

void newGame();
void displayBoard();
bool gameOver();
int generateNum();                       //generate random 2 or 4
void moveInDirection(int);
void generateNumInBoard();

int main()
{
    int currentDirection;
    char command, choice;
    char direction[128];
    string currentName;
    direction['s'] = 0;
    direction['w'] = 1;
    direction['a'] = 3;
    direction['d'] = 2;

    ifstream inFile;
    inFile.open("Score.txt");
    inFile >> name >> highestScore;
    inFile.close();

    ofstream outFile;
    outFile.open("Score.txt");

    cout << "Please enter your name = ";
    getline(cin, currentName);
    newGame();
    while (true)
    {
        system("CLS");
        displayBoard();
        cout << "\nEnter what you want to do = ";
        command = _getche();
        if (command == 'n')
        {
            newGame();
        }
        else if (command == 'e')
        {
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            currentDirection = direction[command];
            moveInDirection(currentDirection);
        }
        if (gameOver())
        {
            if (score > highestScore)
            {
                outFile << currentName << " " << score;
            }
            do {
                system("CLS");
                cout << "YOU HAVE LOST :("
                    << "Your score was " << score << endl
                    << "Do you want to play again ( New game (n) / Exit (e) ) = ";
                command = _getche();
            } while (command != 'n' && command != 'e');
            if (command == 'e')
            {
                exit(1);
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
void newGame()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
        {
            board[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }
    board[0][0] = 2;
}
void displayBoard()
{
    SetConsoleTextAttribute(hConsole, 9);
    cout << "\n2048 THE GAME\n\n a = left , s = down , w = up , d = right , n = newgame , e = exit\n\n If all boxes get filled you lose\n\nBest player = " << name << "   Best score = " << highestScore << "\n\n Your Score = " << score << "\n\n" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < limit; i++)
    {
        cout << "\t\t|";
        for (int j = 0; j < limit; j++)
        {
            if (board[i][j] == 0)
            {
                cout << " - |";
            }
            else
            {
                cout << " " << board[i][j] << " |";
            }
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}
void moveInDirection(int currentDirection)
{
    int count = 0;
    bool flag = false;
    if (currentDirection == 2)
    {
        while (count != 4)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < limit; i++)
            {
                for (int j = limit - 1; j > 0; j--)
                {
                    if ((board[i][j] == board[i][j - 1]) && board[i][j] != 0 && board[i][j - 1] != 0)
                    {
                        board[i][j] += board[i][j - 1];
                        board[i][j - 1] = 0;
                        score += board[i][j];
                    }
                    else if ((board[i][j] == 0) && (board[i][j - 1] != 0))
                    {
                        flag = true;
                        swap(board[i][j], board[i][j - 1]);
                    }
                }
            }
            count++;
        }
        if (flag)
        {
            generateNumInBoard();
        }
    }
    else if (currentDirection == 3)
    {
        while (count != 4)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < limit; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < limit - 1; j++)
                {
                    if ((board[i][j] == board[i][j + 1]) && board[i][j] != 0 && board[i][j + 1] != 0)
                    {
                        board[i][j] += board[i][j + 1];
                        board[i][j + 1] = 0;
                        score += board[i][j];
                    }
                    else if ((board[i][j] == 0) && (board[i][j + 1] != 0))
                    {
                        flag = true;
                        swap(board[i][j], board[i][j + 1]);
                    }
                }
            }
            count++;
        }
        if (flag)
        {
            generateNumInBoard();
        }
    }
    else if (currentDirection == 1)
    {
        while (count != 4)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < limit - 1; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < limit; j++)
                {
                    if ((board[i][j] == board[i + 1][j]) && board[i][j] != 0 && board[i + 1][j] != 0)
                    {
                        board[i][j] += board[i + 1][j];
                        board[i + 1][j] = 0;
                        score += board[i][j];
                    }
                    else if ((board[i][j] == 0) && (board[i + 1][j] != 0))
                    {
                        flag = true;
                        swap(board[i][j], board[i + 1][j]);
                    }
                }
            }
            count++;
        }
        if (flag)
        {
            generateNumInBoard();
        }
    }
    else if (currentDirection == 0)
    {
        while (count != 4)
        {
            for (int i = limit - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < limit; j++)
                {
                    if ((board[i][j] == board[i - 1][j]) && board[i][j] != 0 && board[i - 1][j] != 0)
                    {
                        board[i][j] += board[i - 1][j];
                        board[i - 1][j] = 0;
                        score += board[i][j];
                    }
                    else if ((board[i][j] == 0) && (board[i - 1][j] != 0))
                    {
                        flag = true;
                        swap(board[i][j], board[i - 1][j]);
                    }
                }
            }
            count++;
        }
        if (flag)
        {
            generateNumInBoard();
        }
    }
}
int generateNum()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    int randomNum = rand() % 4;
    if (randomNum <= 2)
    {
        return 2;
    }
    else
    {
        return 4;
    }
}
void generateNumInBoard()
{
    bool flag = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < limit; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < limit; j++)
        {
            if (board[i][j] == 0)
            {
                board[i][j] = generateNum();
                flag = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (flag == false)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
}
bool gameOver()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < limit; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < limit; j++)
        {
            if (board[i][j] == 0)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: What is the 2048 game?  What are the requirements for your code?  What is the expected behavior?  What inputs did you supply?  Please **edit** your post with the answers in text form.

Comment: My advice is to learn how to use your debugger.

Comment: A [debugger](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) is invaluable in tracking down these sorts of issues.

Comment: I recommend using the `switch/case` statement instead the `if-else-if` ladder.

Comment: Thanks @ThomasMatthews I will use Switch Case

Comment: Sometimes creating a [mre] is a useful debugging tool (in addition to making it easier for the people from whom you are asking help).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You made a small blunder at the fucntion **gameOver()** as you are making the game end if the compiler finds any **0** in the 2D array and you are display the zero as **-** in front end , You just need to make he false part true and viceversa.The game will work AOK :-)

```
bool gameOver()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < limit; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < limit; j++)
        {
            if (board[i][j] == 0)
            {
                return false;      //You need to make this false to not end game as soon as it starts
            }
        }
    }
    return true;   //You need to make this true as the end condition
}
```